# Dowel bracket fixture

Tags: joints

I'm not sure if this exists or not.

A flat square piece of plastic or metal which has two or more permanently affixed dowel-type protuberances that allow various boards to be joined simultaneously.
If it exists, would love to know the name so I can shop for them.

[image]

Comment: How about just a bit more clarification. "allow various boards to be joined simultaneously" is something I am having trouble visualizing. Surely not something as simple as a corrugated fastener, or "Jew Nail" as the old-timers call them (no offense meant to any creed, that's the colloquial term).

Comment: Hopefully this link works ... http://imgur.com/leTmAgQ

Comment: Imagine that two of the dowels go into one board, while each of the other two dowels go into one board each (there are three total boards.) This fixture would add some stability to the three boards, depending on how sturdy the bracket material was (have even thought of maybe having it 3D printed.)

Comment: Dude, nice image/drawing with cool shadows (and nice use of perspective with the shadows too), +1. I haven't seen anything like that pre-made but I am thinking of a bunch of ways you could DIY one to your exact custom specs.

Comment: Thanks, used Inkscape to design it.
How do you suggest I make this item?

Comment: Wood, like oak or another strong hardwood. Partially drill holes through a (fairly) thick wood plate with a Forstner bit (makes flat-bottomed holes). Set cut hardwood dowels in and drill through the back of the plate (on center of each dowel) and insert another small dowel through the plate and into the larger dowels, for xtra strength. Use a s*#t ton of carpenter's wood glue and clamp it up to dry. Should be plenty strong?

Comment: So, something like this maybe?
http://imgur.com/cno2wWQ

Comment: xactly! although it might be strong enough without the "cross dowels", depends on the application.

Comment: I'm not sure (and, it seems, I'm not the only one) how you intend to use this, as I don't see how this is going to hold boards together in any secure fashion. If this is going to be structural in any way (i.e. holding up bookshelves, a table, chair, etc.) I'd suggest thoroughly testing its holding capacity before trusting it. For the benefit of the rest of us, it would be nice if you would add a nice drawing or two showing how you intend to use it. @JimmyFix-it has a good suggestion on making it, but I'd substitute a wood screw for the second dowel.

Answer (score 4):

> **I'm not sure if this exists or not.**

Probably not.

However, you have an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

> **I'm trying to build a piece of furniture that I can take apart quickly/easily and set up again in another apartment.**

Commonly used solutions include

### Furniture bolts

[image]

### Mitre bolts

[image]

### Knock-down fittings

AKA furniture blocks

[image]

### Cam lock bolts

[image]

### Woodworking Joints

See https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/creating-a-speaker-stand-using-only-joins/3306#3306

Comment: While I sincerely appreciate the various suggestions for unrelated fixtures, I have already decided to use the fixture described / diagrammed. 

I will 3D print it. 

I was merely asking in this forum, IF THIS FIXTURE ALREADY EXISTS and if so WHAT IT'S CALLED. The answer might be no. 

Einstellung effect notwithstanding, this question does not have a so-called "XY Problem," since I actually do need to know if XYZ Fixture exists or not. I am not seeking/needing advice on the underlying project.